# Stuck with this Ruby logic

Tags: ruby

I had this exercise to solve. From the test i thought i had to initialize the class, but looking at the solution i was thinking the wrong way. Now, i understand pretty much all the code in the solution, but what i don't understand is the logic behind the getter. First of all i would have wrote attr_accessor :title because at the end we write the title, but probably it would have been wrong. Second, what i don't understand is the fact that i believed that every time we call the new method on a class, we have to instantiate it with the method Initialize and assigning the attributes. Third thing i don't understand is this line of code def title=(new_title). What are we exactly doing here? Are we doing it otherwise the following code wouldn't work? Thank you.

```
 @book.title = "inferno"
```

This is the rake file:

```
# # Book Titles
#
# # Topics
#
# * classes and objects
# * instance variables
# * setter methods
# * strings
#
# # Notes
#
# Book Titles in English obey some strange capitalization rules. For example, "and" is lowercase in "War and Peace". This test attempts to make sense of some of those rules.
#

require 'book'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")
    end

    it 'should capitalize every word' do
      @book.title = "stuart little"
      expect(@book.title).to eq("Stuart Little")
    end

    describe 'should capitalize every word except...' do
      describe 'articles' do
        specify 'the' do
          @book.title = "alexander the great"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("Alexander the Great")
        end

        specify 'a' do
          @book.title = "to kill a mockingbird"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("To Kill a Mockingbird")
        end

        specify 'an' do
          @book.title = "to eat an apple a day"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("To Eat an Apple a Day")
        end
      end

      specify 'conjunctions' do
        @book.title = "war and peace"
        expect(@book.title).to eq("War and Peace")
      end

      specify 'prepositions' do
        @book.title = "love in the time of cholera"
        expect(@book.title).to eq("Love in the Time of Cholera")
      end
    end

    describe 'should always capitalize...' do
      specify 'I' do
        @book.title = "what i wish i knew when i was 20"
        expect(@book.title).to eq("What I Wish I Knew When I Was 20")
      end

      specify 'the first word' do
        @book.title = "the man in the iron mask"
        expect(@book.title).to eq("The Man in the Iron Mask")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the solution they give:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(new_title)
    words = new_title.split(" ")
    words = [words[0].capitalize] +
      words[1..-1].map do |word|
        little_words = %w{a an and the in of}
        if little_words.include? word
          word
        else
          word.capitalize
        end
      end
    @title = words.join(" ")
  end

end
```

Comment: 1) attr_accessor defines a getter(`def title`) and a setter(`def title=`) but in this case the setter is a custom implementation so the `attr_reader` is correct (just a getter). 2) the initialize method of `Book` essentially is `def initialize; end` it accepts no arguments and provides no functionality but it does exist via inheritance from `BasicObject`. You are not required to accept any arguments or set any attributes in the `initialize` method. 3) This is converting the given `new_title` to what is commonly referred to as "title case" and assigning it to the instance variable `@title`

Comment: What do you mean when you say " the setter is a custom implementation"? I still don't understand the meaning of this ```title=(new_title)```..you say it is assigning new_title to the instance variable @title..ok, so what in this line? ```@title = words.join(" ")```..is it now doing the same thing again returning the instance variable?

Comment: If you don't understand the question, then how can we understand it, let alone answer it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand the idea about accessors. Many languages have direct access to instance variables. Ruby does not; it thinks that everything from outside the class should go through methods alone. Thus, in order to read or write `@title` from outside, you use accessors.

`attr_accessor` is a convenience method that defines two methods: the attribute reader, and the attribute writer. When you say `attr_accessor :title`, it is equivalent to

```
def title()
  @title
end

def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```

where `title` and `title=` are method names, and `value` is a parameter to the `title=` method. Having done so, you can write

```
book.title=("New title")
puts book.title()
```

to call the setter, and then getter. Ruby gives us a bit of a convenience here, as these are the equivalent syntactic sugar:

```
book.title = "New title"
puts book.title
```

The reason why we want everything to go through methods is, we can customise methods. If we need to make sure we are permitted to read, or if we want to have side effects of setting, we can just switch out an accessor method. But if we do that, we don't need the autogenerated accessor - we'll write our own.

> First of all i would have wrote attr_accessor :title because at the end we write the title, but probably it would have been wrong.

The reader is the same default reader. But the solution wants to make a custom writer, so we'll define it ourselves. Thus, only the reader needs to be autogenerated: `attr_reader :title`.

> Second of all, what i don't fully understand is the fact that i believed that every time we call the new method on a class, we have to instantiate it with the method Initialize and assigning the attributes.

There is an implicit empty `initialize` that gets inherited to every class that doesn't override it. It takes no parameters, and does nothing, pretty much like this:

```
def initialize()
end
```

If you don't write your own `initialize` method, then that one is being used. Since `Book` as described by your spec does not take arguments to `new`, and all interaction with the title goes through the attribute accessors, you don't need anything more than the default empty `initialize`.

> Third thing i don't understand is this line of code def title=(new_title). What are we exactly doing here? Are we doing it otherwise the following code wouldn't work?

As explained above, `def title=(new_title)` is exactly the same syntax as `def factorial(n)`, just with a weird method name. Ruby lets methods end in many unconventional ways: with a question mark to signify boolean result like `equal?`, with an exclamation mark to signify dangerous operation like `sort!`, or with an equal sign to allow for the alternate call syntax masquerading as assignment, as described above.

Comment: Excepting assignment like methods (methods ending in `=`) can only accept a single argument and will always return that object regardless.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Almost always (you can still send more arguments and get a different output if you use `Object#send`). Very good point though.

Comment: @Amadan "The reader is the same default reader. But the solution wants to make a custom writer, so we'll define it ourselves. Thus, only the reader needs to be autogenerated: attr_reader :title." 
Ok so we don't write attr_writer in the solution code gave by the exercise because we are defining a custom one, right? Different from this
```
def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```
and we only write attr_reader :title so then we can call @book.title when we riquiring it the test file, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Amadan Learning coding sometimes makes even difficult explain what you don't understand, but you clarified my doubts. Thank you!